# Where are CUPS backend scripts and filters stored on Mac OS X?

Tags: cups

Where are CUPS backend scripts and filters stored on Mac OS X?

On linux they are in /usr/lib/cups/backend, but I can't find them on Mac OS x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/usr/libexec/cups/backend
/usr/libexec/cups/filter
... etc
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/cups-deviced.8.html ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20150923101336/https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/cups-deviced.8.html))